# Show the existence of a limit of an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, solution-verification, riemann-integration

I was presented the following problem at Calculus class:

Let $f: (0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$. We know that $f$ is Riemann integrable in every compact interval of $(0, \infty)$, and that the limit $\underset{t \to 0^+}{\lim} f(t) = L$ exists.
Show that for all $0 < \alpha < \beta$ we have
$$\lim_{t \to 0^+}\int \limits_{\alpha t}^{\beta t} \frac{f(x)}{x}dx = L \log\frac{\beta}{\alpha}.$$
I showed that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $T>0$ such that
$$(L-\varepsilon)\log\frac{\beta}{\alpha}< \int \limits_{\alpha t}^{\beta t} \dfrac{f(x)}{x}dx < (L+\varepsilon)\log\frac{\beta}{\alpha}.$$
Indeed, it is easy to show using the given limit of $f$: there exists $T>0$ such that for every $0 < t < T$ we have $L-\varepsilon < f(x) < L+\varepsilon$. Then, for every $\beta t < T$
$$\int \limits_{\alpha t}^{\beta t} \frac{f(x)}{x}dx<\int \limits_{\alpha t}^{\beta t} \frac{L + \varepsilon}{x}dx
=\cdots = (L+\varepsilon)\log\frac{\beta}{\alpha}$$

and symmetrically for the lower bound. My professor said that this proof does not show what is needed to be shown, however I cannot see why this is not correct. As I see it, this is exactly what is needed to be shown, following the definition of the limit, i.e.

$$\lim_{t \to 0^+} \int \limits_{\alpha t}^{\beta t} \dfrac{f(x)}{x}dx = L \log\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\iff(L-\varepsilon)\log\frac{\beta}{\alpha}< \int \limits_{\alpha t}^{\beta t} \frac{f(x)}{x}dx < (L+\varepsilon)\log\frac{\beta}{\alpha}.$$

Am I missing something? I will appreciate it if someone could kindly shed a light on this matter.

Comment: This has been asked and answered before: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1470962/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/532785/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3104734/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3112975/42969 – all found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Clim_%7Bt%20%5Cto%200%5E%2B%7D%20%5Cint%20%5Climits_%7B%5Calpha%20t%7D%5E%7B%5Cbeta%20t%7D%20%5Cdfrac%7Bf(x)%7D%7Bx%7Ddx%20%3D%20L%20%5Clog(%5Cdfrac%7B%5Cbeta%7D%7B%5Calpha%7D)%24)

Comment: I think that you also have the right idea and are close to a correct proof. But it is a bit unclear. For example, you say *“I showed that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $T>0$ such that ...”* and then the following does not involve $T$ at all.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks, but I want to know whether my proof is correct. I edited my proof to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Since you hand us the stick to beat you, I shall be (over?)demanding. Ready to hear (unkind?) criticism?

You write "for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $T>0$ such that", followed by some things where $T$ never occurs. The missing piece inbetween is "$\forall t\in(0,T)$". *Edit: since you edited your proof, this problem partially disappeared but there is still a $\forall t$ missing just after "there exists $T>0$ such that".*

What I find more embarrassing is that you stop at $(L-\varepsilon)\log\frac\beta\alpha<\int_{\alpha t}^{\beta t}\frac{f(x)}xdx<(L+\varepsilon)\log\frac\beta\alpha$ and pretend the proof is done. It is not, because your definition of the limit suffers the same sloopiness and lack of quantifiers. Indeed, $\lim_{t\to0^+}\int_{\alpha t}^{\beta t}\frac{f(x)}xdx=L\log\frac\beta\alpha$ is not equivalent to "$(L-\varepsilon)\log\frac\beta\alpha<\int_{\alpha t}^{\beta t}\frac{f(x)}xdx< (L+\varepsilon)\log\frac\beta\alpha$" but to
$$\forall\epsilon>0\quad\exists\delta>0\quad\forall t\in(0,\delta)\quad L\log\frac\beta\alpha-\epsilon<\int_{\alpha t}^{\beta t}\frac{f(x)}xdx<L\log\frac\beta\alpha+\epsilon.$$
So, what is missing here is the choice of $\delta,$ given $\epsilon$ (of course, it will rely on your previous $\forall\varepsilon\exists T\dots$, but some work remains to be done).

Admittedly, this missing piece is boaring to write and you seem to have the right feeling, but your professor probably does not find it sufficient.

Comment: Maybe I did not follow you and made some mistake. But I think that $(L-\varepsilon)\log\frac\beta\alpha<\int_{\alpha t}^{\beta t}\frac{f(x)}xdx< (L+\varepsilon)\log\frac\beta\alpha$ is sufficient to yield the conclusion by substituting $\varepsilon=\frac{\varepsilon'}{\log \frac{\beta}{\alpha}}$. My professor allows students to omit that kind of detail.

Comment: I am sure to have made no mistake. I tried to lead you to a complete and rigorous writing. If your professor allows you to omit boaring details, ok. Then, your only (but repeated) sin was to omit quantifiers, hence to write incomplete statements. E.g. here: make explicit that you choose $\delta=T/\beta.$ If my answer does not satisfy you, better ask directly your professor...

Comment: @AnneBauval Not need to be harsh, Anne. Thanks for your detailed answer.

Comment: Harsh? No, I *really* advise you to ask your professor if you find these explanations unsufficient or unsuitable, since you just told (s)he has personal view of which details are necessary and which are not. But again: beware to always write complete *quantified* statements, not just formulas with free variables like in your definition of the limit.

Comment: @AnneBauval I find these explanations very sufficient. There is just no need to beat anyone with sticks or to call my ideas embarrassing. I wish you the very best

Comment: If you felt any hostility, don't blame me but GoogleTranslate. I honestly *and friendly* did my best to help. "hand us the stick to beat you" was "[donner le bâton pour se faire battre](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/donner_le_b%C3%A2ton_pour_se_faire_battre)", and "embarrassing", which I maintain (it tries to explain why your proof was not appreciated) was "ça me gêne"

Comment: I apologize that I misunderstood you. You emphasize the quantifiers, and I admit that this is important. What I want to say is that, if we end the proof by concluding "$\forall \varepsilon>0$, $\exists T>0$ s.t. ($0<t<T$) $\Longrightarrow ((L-\varepsilon)\log\frac\beta\alpha<\int_{\alpha t}^{\beta t}\frac{f(x)}xdx< (L+\varepsilon)\log\frac\beta\alpha$) ", then this is a complete proof since we can make the substitution $\varepsilon=\frac{\varepsilon'}{\log \frac{\beta}{\alpha}}$. Do you agree with that?

Comment: Yes except that this $T$ is not the $T$ which you wrote before: it is that $T$ divided by $\beta.$